# How to attach the type to a library globally available on Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

I'm loading a JS library using the old fashion way (loadScript, `<script>` in DOM, whatever...), I have the typings available, but I don't understand how I can tell to Typescript that  `window.myLibrary` is the constructor of my library and match the type I already have.

Let's say this import would import the dependency and the typings in the same time

```
import { MyLibrary } from "myLibrary";


[..]


new MyLibrary("#div", {});
```

That's way too recent for my stack. I only want to import the typings using Webpack and attach it to some `window['myLibrary']` variable, but still benefits of the typescript type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to attach the type to the library instance

```js
// Import the typings directly
import { MyLibrary } from "../../../../../defs/myLib-4.5";

[...]


// the magic line that attach the type to the window attribute
const GlobalLibraryConstructor = (window as any)['myLibrary'] as typeof MyLibrary;
this.table = new GlobalLibraryConstructor("#div", {});
```

Hope it will help you !